# Cannot connect Java socket server and client

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am learning about socket programming with Java. Using Java 8, have this simple server:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("MY IP address is " + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
        ServerSocket server     = new ServerSocket(4031);
        Socket socket           = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Yay somebody connected! " + socket);
        socket.close();
        server.close();
    }
}
```

All it does is show the host's address and then wait for a socket to connect.

And have this client:

```
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Trying to connect...");
        Socket s = new Socket("123.456.7.890", 4031);
        System.out.println("Cool");
        s.close();
    }
}
```

---

When I run the server and the client in my house (in two different computers), this works: I simply grab the IP address displayed by the server, supply it to the client, and the connection is established.

Now I have this same server in my house, whereas I am running my client in the office. Under the same process, I supplied the IP address printed by the server to my client. However, the connection is never established: neither the server or the client generate a socket.

- Happens with both Java 7 and 8.
- Tried several different ports.
- No exceptions are thrown. Both programs just hang in there, waiting.
- I am using Mac OSX Mavericks 10.9.5 on both machines.
- The firewalls are turned off on both machines.
- They are indeed connected to the internet. In fact, I used Chrome Remote Desktop to control the server and check its status.
- This works fine when both machines are in the same house. But not when one is in the house and another somewhere else.
- And yes, this works for localhost too.

The above points seem to suggest that the issue is with the IP address I used to connect to my server. Maybe `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` is not suitable for this - although it puzzles me why does this work with two machines in the same house.

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Post the stack trace in your question. Always. This code will not block forever. I suspect you're getting a connection timeout. It happens after a minute or so. Maybe you weren't patient enough.

Comment: @Voldemort, did you analyze the problem further?

Answer (score 2):

You say that your firewalls are turned off on both machines, but you also have to make sure that

1. you connect to your *public* IP. The IP that your server reports is probably the LAN IP that you've received from your router through DHCP
2. You also have to make sure that your router is configured to forward connections to port 4031 of your public IP to the IP of your server (and not to some other machine on your local network).

Finally, there's a small risk that your ISP forbids setting up servers at home. In this case they may be so evil that they block incoming connections.

Comment: Curiously when I use the public IP, even if the server and client are both in the same machine, it doesn't work. I suppose the issue is with the router then - I'm not sure how to configure that but I'll take a look now.

Comment: I'm not surprised you can't connect to your public IP from within your network.

Comment: Here's a good resource for configuring port forwarding: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/

Comment: @Voldemort Are you sure you have 'public IP' assigned to you by ISP? If not, 'office-home' connection won't work, unless you can make ssh tunnel from home to office (if so, you can use 'ssh port forwarding'). Keep in mind, most of the time, office net admins won't take such tunnelling lightly, unless this is explicitly permitted at work (i.e., you've asked net admin about it).

Comment: I didn't know about the need in port forwarding, Thanks!